# How to edit form with data from database tables in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am doing project in laravel. I want edit form with database table values.

In controller,

```
$event_note = DB::table('event_note')->where('event_id',$id)->first();
```

I have **blade.php** file for particular textarea as,

```
<div class="form-group clearfix{{ $errors->has('event_note') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
       <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Note</label>
       <div class="col-md-6">
           <textarea class="form-control" name="event_note" rows="4" cols="50">{{ $event_note->note }}</textarea>

            @if ($errors->has('event_note'))
                   <span class="help-block">
                  <strong>{{ $errors->first('event_note') }}</strong>
                  </span>
            @endif
      </div>
</div>
```

but as event_note doesn't have any record it throws an error as,

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:....

for variable $event_note->note.

I don't know how to edit this form if database table dont have any value it should show an empty textarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`or ''`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data) clause:

```
{{ $event_note->note or '' }}
```

It's a Blade shortcut for this solution:

```
{{ isset($event_note->note) ? $event_note->note : '' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

"first()" will return "null" if nothing is found in database for this id.

Try this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="event_note" rows="4" cols="50">{{ is_null($event_note) ? null : $event_note->note }}</textarea>
```